# SQL: replacing a value with corresponding values in differet table after join

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I have 3 tables:

Table: `Info` looks like

```
id Name code_category_id code_confirmed_status_id
5  I001 266              49
10 I005 267              48
```

Table `Survey` looks like

```
worker_id code_number_of_days_id code_gender
5           413                     7
10          412                     8
```

Table `code` looks like

```
id type                value
413 number_of_days     4
412 number_of_days     5
266 category_id        25-32
267 category_id        30-35
 48 confirmed_status   Full-time
 49 confirmed_status   Part-time
  7 gender             Male
  8 gender             Female
```

I want to join these tables such that I have all the information where the code numbers are replaced by code value. My final table

```
 worker_id code_number_of_days_id code_gender Name code_category_id code_confirmed_status_id
 5         4                      Male        I001                  Full-time   
 10        5                     Female       I005                  Part-time
```

I can combine the tables using join

```
select survey.worker_id,
       survey.code_number_of_days_id,
       survey.code_gender,
       Info.Name, 
       Info.code_category_id, 
       Info.code_confirmed_status_id
from Survey 
  full outer join Info 
    on Survey.worker_id = Info.id
```

The result is the table I want but the codes are some numbers, I want them replaced with specific code values in the code table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think the query below is what you are looking for

```
select survey.worker_id,
   (Select Value from Code where ID = survey.code_number_of_days_id) as No_of_Days,
   (Select Value from Code where ID = survey.code_gender) as Gender,
   Info.Name, 
   (Select Value from Code where ID = Info.code_category_id) as Category,
   (Select Value from Code where ID = Info.code_confirmed_status_id) as Confirmed,
from Survey 
full outer join Info 
on Survey.worker_id = Info.id
```